# Databricks Pyhton creating and using Customer class

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

I have created a Customer class that I want to use in my main code.

**Model/customer.py**

```
###
#
# File: Model/customer.py
# Version 1.0.0
#
###


class Customer:
    """ A class representing an customer. """

    __name = None
    __name_abbreviated = None


    # Initialize Model class ----------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, name='', name_abbreviated=''):
        """ Initializes customer class with blank values. """
        self.__name= name
        self.__name_abbreviated = name_abbreviated
```

Now i want to use the Customer class in my main notebook, however this seems to be difficult:

**main notebook:**

```
# COMMAND ----------

# MAGIC %run "Model/customer"

customer = Customer('Big Corporation', 'BC')


# COMMAND ----------
```

This gives me error:

```
NameError: name 'Customer' is not defined
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback
     3 # MAGIC %run "Model/customer"
---> 5 customer = Customer('Big Corporation', 'BC')


NameError: name 'Customer' is not defined
```

Comment: spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("dbfs:/FileStore/code/customer.py")  please change the path to your location.

Comment: If you have the customer class in another notebook then try running this in your main notebook. %run /users/customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally use relative paths:
%run ./Model/cusomter.py

and you should split the %run and the customer variable assignment in different cells.